# vi over netcat session

Tags: shell, vi, netcat

Is it possible to use vi over netcat?

server:

```
mkfifo tun; sh tun | netcat -l 4444 > tun
```

client:

```
netcat SERVER_IP 4444
```

Will gave me remote shell, but it's a problem to send special hot-keys, for example I can't push **ESC** to enter "*normal mode*" in *vi*.

Or best choice will be *sed* ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This command runs input from nc as a script, and it will fail for the same reason why this script won't edit a file:

```
#!/bin/sh
vi file
42G
dd
:wq
```

You can instead, ironically, use `script` to avoid running it as a script, and instead get a terminal session to interact with:

```
server$ mkfifo tun; script -q < tun | netcat -l 4444 > tun
```

(some netcats require `-p` before the port above)

Additionally, you should disable local echo and line buffering so that keys pass through the connection immediately rather than when pressing enter:

```
client$ stty -icanon -echo; nc localhost 4444
```

You should now be able to edit files in `vi`.

This is obviously a neat proof of concept only. Non-root users who want to provide robust shell access over the network should use `sshd`.